# jqgrid custom JSON data no error but not showing data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jqgrid

I have been working with jqGrid for a while, and I was just trying to create a new server-side script to return data to a client-side grid. A lot of times I try to get back to the basics of these software programs.  I wanted to return JSON data to my grid, just have it load once with no pager.  After referencing the documentation [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data), I tried to create my JSON string to match the format from the docs, like this:

```
{ 
  "total": "xxx", 
  "page": "yyy", 
  "records": "zzz",
  "rows" : [
    {"id" :"1", "cell" :["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
    {"id" :"2", "cell":["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
      ...
  ]
}
```

Here is the JS grid definition:

```
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url:'/dataurl.php',
    shrinkToFit: true,
    autowidth: true,
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    postData:{
        'arg1':'load_data',
        'num_days':$('#num_of_days_input').val()
    },
    colNames:[
        'Ship_Date',
        'Insert/Label',
        'Customer',
        'JobNum',
        'QNTYOrdered',
        'DEL',
        'Ship_Type',
        'Carrier',
        'Time',
        'Status'
    ],
    colModel:[
        {width:20,name:'Ship_Date', index:'Ship_Date'},
        {width:20,name:'InsertorLabel', index:'InsertorLabel'},
        {width:20,name:'Customer', index:'Customer'},
        {width:20,name:'JobNum', index:'JobNum'},
        {width:20,name:'QNTYOrdered', index:'QNTYOrdered'},
        {width:20,name:'DEL', index:'DEL'},
        {width:20,name:'Ship_Type', index:'Ship_Type', edittype:'select', editoptions:{value:"Partial:Partial;Balance:Balance;Full:Full"}},
        {width:20,name:'Carrier', index:'Carrier', edittype:'select', editoptions:{value:"UPS:UPS;Fed Ex:Fed Ex;2D:2D;T&M:T&M;Cougar:Cougar"}},
        {width:20,name:'Time', index:'Time', edittype:'select', editoptions:{value:"before 7am:before 7am;7-9am:7-9am;9-12am:9-12am;12-3pm:12-3pm;after 3pm:after 3pm"}},
        {width:20,name:'Status', index:'Status', edittype:'select', editoptions:{value:"To Ship:To Ship;Ship Pending:Ship Pending"}}
    ],
    loadonce: true,
    sortname: 'Ship_Date',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Shipping Request',
    loadError: function(xhr, status, error){
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert(status);
        alert(error);
    },
    loadComplete: function(data){
        alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    }
});
```

I had done quite a bit of debugging using the `loadError` method, and now that I am getting no errors, I can see my data returned from the server.  To me it looks like the format is correct:

[image]

But, alas, the grid still appears empty there.  Am I still missing something?  Thanks!

Comment: Apply here full url path and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `rows` property of the JSON response from the server **have to be array**, but you use object instead (it should be `"rows": [{}]`, but you use `"rows": {}` instead). Even if you have only one item you should still return the array with one of the item.